# Spring Data JPA @query tag is not validating null values with Postgres DB

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jpql

```
@Query("from PrsBookingProcess pbp where (:bookingOwnerCode='' OR pbp.bookingOwnerCode = :bookingOwnerCode)"
        + "and (pbp.crtDttime BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate)"
        + "and (:bookingProcStatus is null OR pbp.bookingProcStatus = :bookingProcStatus)"
List<PrsBookingProcess> findByPnrbydateRangeandOperator(
        @Param("bookingOwnerCode") String bookingOwnerCode, 
        @Param("fromDate") Calendar fromDate,
        @Param("toDate") Calendar toDate, 
        @Param("bookingProcStatus") String bookingProcStatus);
```

This is my JPA query to hit Postgres DB. My bookingOwnerCode value takes null only if I check there value with empty quotes(''). If i check by making them :BookingOwnerCode is null and giving them null from UI it will not fetch me records.

As in case of bookingProcStatus. If i do not give any value in UI and run for above query it will not fetch me anything until and unless i give some value to it.

I am using PGAdmin3 for postgrep and JPA for querying.

Comment: `:bookingOwnerCode=''` I think you want to use the column name here

Comment: i think above is equivalent to ,
@Param("bookingOwnerCode") String bookingOwnerCode so this will be having value coming from UI.

Comment: same query works in oracle DB. But i need to migrate it to postgres. So above problem is coming.

Comment: If "same query works in oracle DB" then you can look in the LOG and see what SQL is being invoked for both. aka debugging

Comment: Oracle does not distinguish between an empty string `''`  and `null` so the difference in behaviour probably comes from there

Comment: i tried passing forceful null values into this. but got below error.
avax.el.ELException: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `:bookingOwnerCode is null OR :bookingOwnerCode = ''` instead of just `:bookingOwnerCode = ''`.

Or you could write a unit/integration test that verifies the expected behaviour.